# Why we cannot declare a function argument static?

Tags: c++, static, c++14

I have been curious about why c++ does not allow declaring a static function argument as shown below:

```
int test(static int a )
{
     return a;
}

int main()
{

    test(5);
    return 0;
}
```

output console shows:

> ```
> error: storage class specifiers invalid in parameter declarations
> error: storage class specified for parameter 'a'
> ```

**Update #1:**
I can achieve my requirements like follows:

```
int test(int a )
{
     static int count = 0;// <-- I want to eliminate this line due to some project constraints.
     count += a; 
     return count;
}
```

I cannot use passing arguments by reference if you suggest, I have already tried considering that option.
If there is any other way to accomplish above behavior, you're welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect it to have? It's unintuitive to me, so an explanation of expectations would be nice. You're free to consider proposing it and discussing such on std-proposals.

Comment: There are lots of nonsensical things C++ doesn't allow, why pick on this one?

Comment: Please explain how this would be different from passing variables normally?

Comment: @chris post updated. does it clarifies my question now?

Comment: @PralhadPatil So you want to ignore all new values of `a` other than those of the very first invocation? That's a highly unusual requirement.

Comment: @hvd sorry, it is something like --> static int count += a;

Comment: @PralhadPatil That's a syntax error. If you meant `static int count; count += a;`, then it wouldn't make any sense for a parameter `static int a` (if it were valid) to have that as its meaning. What's the "some project constraints" that you're fighting? Be specific, and you just might get a useful answer. Be vague, and no one can know what you mean.

Comment: This question is a candidate to be put on hold.

Comment: @hvd yes, you are right. I wanted to say `static int count; count += a;` I will check & get back to you if I could share those constraints in public domain.

Comment: This is a poor question.  Either it is a question about standardization, or it is question about how to solve a problem, and in *either* case it is a poor one.  If you want to illustrate what the constraints are, @Yakk me and I'll reconsider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare a function static you would do it as such

```
static int test(int a )
{
     return a;
}
```

You are trying to pass in a "static int a" into a function but there's no reason to do that. You would instead declare

```
static int a;
```

somewhere in the class and then simply pass in a to the static method created above as so

```
test(a);
```

Comment: You are correct, but I have some restrictions. I cannot simply use this solution. I have added some more details to my post. Plz check.